# How to find the eigenvectors of this $3 \times 3$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

I need to find eigenvectors of the following matrix?

\begin{bmatrix}2&6&-15\\1&1&-5\\1&2&-6\end{bmatrix}

What I have done: I found eigenvalue $\lambda = -1$, then

\begin{bmatrix}3&6&-15\\1&2&-5\\1&2&-5\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}1\;&2\;&-5\:\end{bmatrix}

$$x_1 = \begin{bmatrix}3\\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}\qquad x_2 = \begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$ **How to find the last one?**

Comment: There is no third eigenvector. Instead, there is a 2 by 2 Jordan block, as the minimum polynomial is $(x+1)^2.$

Comment: Take your original matrix as $A,$ let the next be $B = A + I.$ We have $B^2 = 0.$ So, take any vector $w$ that is not already an eigenvector of $A,$ meaning $Bw \neq 0.$  Relatively small numbers if we choose $w = (1,0,0)^T$ column vector. Then calculate $v=Bw,$ this $v$ really is an eigenvector. Finally, take an independent eigenvector, call it $u.$ The change of basis matrix is going to be $P,$ where the three columns of $P$ are $u,v,w$ in order. Find $P^{-1},$ and $J= P^{-1}AP$ will be in Jordan form.

Comment: @WillJagy Are you saying then that there is a generalized eigenvector associated to $-1$ so that we can complete a basis for $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: There is no third eigenvector because the first two columns of your matrix are just multiples of each other.

Comment: @Math1000 yes.. I put an answer, the columns of $P$ are a basis

Comment: subtract $\lambda$ from  the diagonals and take the determinant and set it equal to 0 and solve for $\lambda$ usually by factoring this will give you all the eigen values then use those to find the vectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I indicated in comment, take

$$
P =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
-2 & 3 & 1 \\
1&1&0 \\
0&1&0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
then calculate $P^{-1}$ and finally $ J=P^{-1} AP,$ where $A$ is your original matrix. I got lucky, as this $\det P = 1.$

The reason it is important to practice finding such a $P$ is that most applications use the reverse order, namely expressing $A = PJ P^{-1}$